# Issue with HR2 installation

Tags: 2011, odata

We have installed Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2. We are facing some issues with Odata after the installation. OData is not coming up as expected and is throwing the below error.

**could not initialize class com.tridion.weservices.odata.input.handler.Odatawebservicehandler**
[image]

After some initial checks, we found out that the issue was caused due to ugc_webservice.jar.
If we remove the jar, Odata is working fine.Can anyone tell us why is the jar included.Is there a way to fix this? What is the impact if this jar is not placed in Odata server.

Comment: You only need this jar if you use the UGC (Comments & Ratings) feature of Tridion - clearly this doesn't seem to be the case, so it's safe to remove it from your webapp. BTW, you get this error because the UGC bundle is not defined in your storage configuration.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the roles you have installed in your system.

In the HR2 comes all the jars that must be updated depending on your initial setup.

It seems that you don't have UGC installed, then you don't need to include the **ugc_webservice** in your update.

You can see this [url](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#docid=reference_DB20ECA59C824CC3BBB4644187D2C57A&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=ReferenceCDJARs.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocreference_DB20ECA59C824CC3BBB4644187D2C57A&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=jars&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1401178762839&currentQuery=jars&currentScope=) (*login required*) to see the list of jars needed to be included, in case you have installed a certain role.