# How to rollback Tridion HR2

Tags: 2011, installation, 2011-sp1

We have installed Tridion 2011 SP1 HR#2 on the Content Manager Server. We want to rollback the same. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "We want to rollback the same". Do you want to rollback the hotfix rollup? Have you upgraded from an earlier version of Tridion and wish to rollback the entire upgrade?

Comment: We want to rollback the hotfix rollup

Comment: Don't give up! http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5674/issue-with-hr2-installation

Comment: It would help us a lot if you would say why you think you need to roll it back...

Answer (score 3):

Is there any specific reason you want to rollback?

There is no direct way to rollback, you have to do it manually. You either have to install HR1 followed by other CM patches(if you earlier had).

If you have DB backup, then it would be bit little easy.

Related Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508863/is-it-possible-to-rollback-tridion-sp1-hr1-to-tridion-sp1

Comment: Beat me to it Raj! :-)